# ListView height not adjusting to content

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, xamarin

I am struggling with Xamarin and the layout for an Android application. I have a ListView as shown in the code below, but whenever I populate it with more than one city, the ListView doesn't expand. Instead I need to scroll it, while the hight only allows for showing one item at a time.

What I really want is the ListView to expand as it contains more and more items. But at the same time, I don't want the keyboard to cover the EditText-fields. It feels that I have tried Everything, including putting everything inside a scrollview and setting layout_height for the ListView to wrap_content. But it just won't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:paddingLeft="15px"
        android:paddingRight="15px"
        android:paddingBottom="15px"
        android:paddingTop="15px"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <TextView
            android:text="Select algorithm:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView1" />
        <RadioGroup
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Greedy Best first Search"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1" />
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A* Best First Search"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2" />
        </RadioGroup>
        <TextView
            android:text="Add location coordinates:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:paddingTop="30px" />
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listViewCoords" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <EditText
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/editTextX" />
            <EditText
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/editTextY" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:text="Add"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonAdd" />
        <Button
            android:text="Clear all"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonClear" />
        <Button
            android:text="Find shortest path"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonSearch" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use ListView into ScrollView. It's too wrong in many ways.

If you want to use Lists into Scrollable content, use **RecyclerView** and Wrap them with **NestedScrollView**.

Answer (score 0):

**Listviews must not be placed under ScrollView**. I don't see any other issues in your code.